# Sprint MVC @ModelAttribute POST not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, post, model-view-controller, modelattribute

I have this problem where I call API with get and it works fine while it gives empty object in case of POST. Below are the code snippets.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/demo")
public class DemoController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/create")
    public ModelAndView createUser(@ModelAttribute User user) {
    ...
    ...
    }
}
```

GET: localhost:8080/demo/create.json?name=test&title=this works fine
POST using form-data is not working. I am getting empty object.

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String title;

    ...
}
```

Comment: So with a POST request, the `createUser` method is being invoked - but the `User` object has a null `name` and `title`?

Comment: Can you show the form.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following code.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView createUser() {

   ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/createuser.jsp");
   modelAndView.addObject("user", new User());
   return modelAndView;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView createUserProcess(@ModelAttribute("user") User user,) {
  // save user to db

}
```

Just out of curiosity. Shouldn't you be displaying the form with createUser and processing it with createUserProcess? Also make sure your form has the following:

```
<form:form commandName="user" modelAttribute="user"> 


</form:form>
```

Comment: What have you changed? A `@RequestMapping` without a `method` attribute handles all HTTP request types.

Comment: I assumed you wanted to display a form then process it. I didn't pass anything to the createUser since there is no need. If createUser is your form processing code then change createUserProcess to createUser. Other  than that you cannot have the same method accept GET and POST method (well at least the last time I checked)

Comment: As OP's code stands, their `createUser` method will handle both POST and GET. The changes you've proposed don't change anything to the actual problem (which we still don't actually know).

Comment: It wouldn't be best practice to handle both POST and GET, even if that is possible. Just trying to help. It would have helped if he posed the code for the form.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your kind replies. I was using Postman to validate my controller. I found I need to add multipart resolver.

Below is the line that fixed it.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you add this exactly? I am facing the same issue.